# cakephp with 2 databases for login and crud

Tags: php, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have been trying to recreate an application for straight PHP to CakePHP and I been running into a few problem along the way.  I have used the [tutorial for Cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) which was most helpful.

The first problem is that I have two databases that one read the login information and one writes the information to the other database for that logged in user.  The kicker is that it's using ODBC database not MySql which I was hoping for.

The second is how to tie the Crud and login controllers together with the two databases.

Any help will do, I've trying to learn and use CakePHP in my spare time.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple database configs in database.php:

```
$default = { //settings };
$secondary = { //settings };
```

Then in your model, set which config it uses by settings its $useDBConfig property:

```
var $useDbConfig = 'secondary';
```

So just set your user model to use one database, and your tables relating to CRUD using another.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Does CakePHP have a built in driver for ODBC?